# how to get rid of typescript error message "Cannot find module 'localforage'"

Tags: cordova, vim, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am doing an ionic 2/cordova project and am using vim with typescript support.

i have the following line in my code:

```
import * as localforage from "localforage";
```

the code is running without problems but the typescript compiler gives the following error

```
/path/to/file.ts|2 col 30 error| Cannot find module 'localforage'.
```

any hints how to avoid that error?

UPDATE

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import * as localforage from "localforage";

@Injectable()
export class DbService {

  constructor() {
    //this.run();
  }

  setKeyVal(k, v){
    console.log("db service setKeyVal");
    let ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
    localforage.setItem(k, device.uuid).then(function () {
      return localforage.getItem(k);
    }).then(function (value) {
      console.log(value);
      // we got our value
      console.log(navigator.connection.type);
      console.log("setItem then");
    }).catch(function (err) {
      // we got an error
      console.log("setItem catch");
    });
  }
}
```

UPDATE 1 - typings.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "cordova-ionic": "registry:dt/cordova-ionic#0.0.0+20160316155526",
    "es6-shim": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/es6-shim/es6-shim.d.ts#4de74cb527395c13ba20b438c3a7a419ad931f1c",
    "localforage": "registry:dt/localforage#0.0.0+20160316155526"
  }
}
```

UPDATE 2 - tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "!node_modules/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed definitions for it: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/localForage/localForage.d.ts ?

Comment: hey, thx for the tipp. i now added localforage typings via ```typings install --ambient --save localforage``` now i got the error ```error| Property 'setItem' does not exist on type 'typeof "localforage"'``` what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code with error?

Comment: i updated the open question

Comment: I have posted my suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - install type definitions from: [localforage](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/localForage/localForage.d.ts)

Second - change your import to:

```
import {localforage} from 'localforage';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to install typeings for localforage but it didn't work for me.

```
typings install localforage --ambient --save
```

But I'm able to do it with tds.

```
npm i tsd -g
tsd install localforage
```

I'm using Ionic2 version Beta.29

Update /typeings/index.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="localForage/localForage.d.ts" />
```

add this line.

Finally, import as

```
import {localforage} from 'localforage';
```

That's it everything will work fine now.

Comment: I dont have  `/typings/index.d.ts`

Comment: @nottinhill If you try `$ typings install localforage` before, you'll get the `/typings/index.d.ts` file.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the `typings install` and the `tsd install` commands. But none of them worked. Finally I found the solution from the ionic forum: [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/localforage-in-typescript/52679/8?u=javaxu).

Hope this helps if someone have the same problem.

#### Step 1: Install Mozilla localForage.

```
$ npm install localforage --save
```

#### Step 2: Install localForage Type Definitions.

```
$ npm install -g typings
$ typings install dt~localforage --save --global
```

I didn't change the import to `import {localforage} from 'localforage';`. Just leave it as

```
import LocalForage from 'localforage';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had runtime error Cannot find module "localforage". I ran commands

```
npm uninstall --save @ionic/storage
npm install --save @ionic/storage
```

It helped in my case